# Chrome DevTools Protocol Fetch Domain. Intercept image requests

Tags: javascript, c#, python-3.x, go, google-chrome-devtools

The [fulfillRequest](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/#method-fulfillRequest) method, as an argument to the `body`, takes a string, as the documentation says, but it does not say that this string should be encoded in `base64`. Thanks to Google, I found an [example](https://forum.katalon.com/t/intercepting-request-with-chrome-devtools-protocol/36081) revealing this secret on the Internet and it went, but now I’m stuck at the moment, how do I transfer the response to image requests in this method?

The page loads excellently. Files of scripts, styles are loaded. How to transmit images is not clear.

I tried to save the image to disk and then send the encoded base64 representation to the `body`. The page remains at `readyState === "interactive"` until it is forced to stop loading.

Any working example in any language will be very helpful.

Comment: Try using Fetch.getResponseBody to see an example.

Comment: I intercept the request -> send it to the client -> the client sends the request through the proxy -> the server returns a response to the client -> the client passes the server response to the method `fulfillRequest` -> the browser considers that the response is received and makes the next request, which is also intercepted.

There are no problems with requests that receive text, or text files with scripts and styles, but when an image appears in the HTML markup and the browser asks for it, I don’t know how to provide it to the browser.

`Fetch.getResponseBody` - can't help with this.

Comment: AFAICT getResponseBody for an image request will show you an example of how its body should look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I followed your advice and it turned out that I was doing everything right, but the error was provoked by a built-in language function that, when decoding a file object into a `base64-string`, inserted a `\n`-character after every 76 bytes. The resulting string was not valid for the browser, which caused a conflict.